# install Apache spark on ubuntu for pyspark

Tags: python-2.7, pyspark, ubuntu-16.04

What is the simple and step by step guide for installing Apache spark 2.0 in Ubuntu(16.04) local machine accessed using python(pyspark). I have tried to search web most of them end up in one or other error.

Comment: This question is too broad. Please instead list the methods you have tried, and the errors you have encountered.

Comment: let me put it this way, would you mind sharing a link in stack overflow where we have steps to install apache spark for ubuntu 16 locally for pyspark.

Comment: You could ask on https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Knowing the "one or other error" is pretty crucial to troubleshooting...

Comment: I saw few posts on askubuntu.com and few on the web and none of them was working correctly. So intention was to share a list of curated steps that actually works.

Answer (score 2):

Courtesy : https://www.santoshsrinivas.com/installing-apache-spark-on-ubuntu-16-04/

I am writing my steps here as I saw few steps are different than expected (at least for ubuntu 16.04)

So here are the steps

step 1:

Download the latest pre-built version from http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html

step 2:
Unzip and move Spark

```
cd ~/Downloads/  
tar xzvf spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz  
mv spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/ spark  
sudo mv spark/ /usr/lib/
```

step 3:
Install SBT

```
echo "deb https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian /" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt.list  
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 2EE0EA64E40A89B84B2DF73499E82A75642AC823  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install sbt
```

Note:- you might have some issues in this step. so please refer the link provided at the end.

step 4:
make sure Java is installed. if not

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:webupd8team/java  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

step 5:
Configure Spark

```
cd /usr/lib/spark/conf/  
cp spark-env.sh.template spark-env.sh  
vi spark-env.sh
```

and add following

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle  
SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=4g
```

step 6:
configure bash file.

open the bashrc file using below command

```
vi ~/.bashrc(if you want to use vi editor)
subl ~/.basrc(if you want to use sublime)
```

copy the below in the bashrc file

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle  
export SBT_HOME=/usr/share/sbt-launcher-packaging/bin/sbt-launch.jar  
export SPARK_HOME=/usr/lib/spark  
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin  
export PATH=$PATH:$SBT_HOME/bin:$SPARK_HOME/bin:$SPARK_HOME/sbin
```

start the bash file using below command

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

step 7:
try now

```
pyspark
```

Note: in case you get stuck with sbt installation (usual case for ubuntu 16.04) try the below link

https://askubuntu.com/questions/771839/problem-installing-package-git-all/771889#771889